# First question is not working (Oops)

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

This time it's not working (and I tried the refresh XD)

The first question review page https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?pagesize=15&filter=day gives me a `Oops! Something Bad Happened!`

Fist answer, low quality and late are working.

Comment: working on this, sql server is choosing a very very odd query plan ... will have to guide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all started a few days ago ....

The query was working fine on SO ... except that it was timing out on SF and SU. I isolated that the issue was due to SQL choosing a crazy query plan for a 1 day range that involved working its way through billions of rows, which is weird cause non of the tables have billions of rows.

This issue was not a "bad plan in the query cache" which bites us a lot, it was a "insane plan generated" issue which is much more rare and subtle.

I mucked around with the query a bit and got it working on SU and SF, however as a side-effect this broke SO.

So I decided to coerce SQL to do a reasonable thing and added a JOIN hint, to force it to do a hash join, since it really needs to work through a fair amount of data even for short time ranges.

This seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'm reproducing this error as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions

The page code says:

```
<!-- Actual error:
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.-->
```

Also, I suspect the technician cat pictured on the error page is high on catnip.  Please consider the professional image the site intends to portray, and consider photoshopping that image so the cat doesn't look so happy and comfortable.